# Rails: get the first n active record objects of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need a way to get the first n items of a model. `Item.first(n)`, `Item.all[1..n]` will do that, except they return an array, not an object.
How do I get it as an ActiveRecord Object?

```
irb(main):135:0> Player.where(game_id: 1).class
=> Player::ActiveRecord_Relation    #Ok
irb(main):136:0> Game.first.players.class
=> Player::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy    #Ok
irb(main):137:0> Player.where(game_id: 1).first(2).class
=> Array   #Not Ok
```

I want to run `update_all` on the returned collection of players, and I can't do that on an array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do `.limit(n)`

Combine this with `.offset` and you have pagination.